# Measurement operator in a Bell experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, linear-algebra

I'm trying to figure out why a Bell experiment gives rise to the payoff (measurement) operator used in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0605134) on quantum game theory.

Two players are each in control of one half of an entangled pair of spin 1/2 particles.

> The spin projection of Player 1's particle is measured either along positive $x$ axis ($P_{1}$)  or along positive $z$ axis (whose value is $P_{2}$) with random alternation.

> The spin projection of Player 2's particle is measured either along  the line $45$ degrees  between positive $x$ and $z$ axes ($Q_{1}$),  or along the line $45$ degrees between negative $x$  and positive $z$ axes ($Q_{2}$), again in random alternation.

Both players want to maximize the value of
\begin{eqnarray}
\Pi \equiv P_1Q_1-P_2Q_2.
\end{eqnarray}

The author claims that the relevant payoff (measurement) operator for each player is:
\begin{eqnarray}
\sqrt{2} \left(  \sigma_x\otimes\sigma_x + \sigma_z\otimes\sigma_z \right)
\end{eqnarray}
where $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_z$ are the usual Pauli matrices.

Can someone explain why this is so?